# Model definition does not give any output

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logmodel = LogisticRegression()
logmodel
```

The output of the above code is just

```
LogisticRegression()
```

But I expected something more detailed, including the model parameters, i.e.:

```
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
                   intercept_scaling=1, l1_ratio=None, max_iter=100,
                   multi_class='auto', n_jobs=None, penalty='l2',
                   random_state=None, solver='lbfgs', tol=0.0001, verbose=0,
                   warm_start=False)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a change in the default [configuration settings](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.set_config.html#sklearn.set_config) from scikit-learn v0.23 onwards; from the [changelog](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.23.html#id13):

> The default setting `print_changed_only` has been changed from False to True. This means that the `repr` of estimators is now more concise and only shows the parameters whose default value has been changed when printing an estimator. You can restore the previous behaviour by using `sklearn.set_config(print_changed_only=False)`. Also, note that it is always possible to quickly inspect the parameters of any estimator using `est.get_params(deep=False)`.

In other words, in versions before v0.23, the following code:

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
# 0.22.2

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr
```

produces the following output with all model parameters:

```
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
                   intercept_scaling=1, l1_ratio=None, max_iter=100,
                   multi_class='auto', n_jobs=None, penalty='l2',
                   random_state=None, solver='lbfgs', tol=0.0001, verbose=0,
                   warm_start=False)
```

But the same code from v0.23 onwards:

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
# 0.23.2

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr
```

will produce just:

```
LogisticRegression()
```

in cases like here, i.e. where no parameter has been explicitly defined, and all remain in their default values. And that's because the `print_changed_only` parameter is now set by default to `True`:

```
sklearn.get_config()

# result:

{'assume_finite': False,
 'working_memory': 1024,
 'print_changed_only': True,
 'display': 'text'}
```

To get all the parameters printed in the newer scikit-learn versions, you should either do

```
lr.get_params()

# result

{'C': 1.0,
 'class_weight': None,
 'dual': False,
 'fit_intercept': True,
 'intercept_scaling': 1,
 'l1_ratio': None,
 'max_iter': 100,
 'multi_class': 'auto',
 'n_jobs': None,
 'penalty': 'l2',
 'random_state': None,
 'solver': 'lbfgs',
 'tol': 0.0001,
 'verbose': 0,
 'warm_start': False}
```

or change the setting (preferable, since it will affect any and all models used afterwards):

```
sklearn.set_config(print_changed_only=False) # needed only once
lr # as defined above

# result

LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
                   intercept_scaling=1, l1_ratio=None, max_iter=100,
                   multi_class='auto', n_jobs=None, penalty='l2',
                   random_state=None, solver='lbfgs', tol=0.0001, verbose=0,
                   warm_start=False)
```