# Display all parameters of an estimator including defaults

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using Watson Studio and using a markdown notebook.  In the notebook, I write the code:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
Tree_Loan= DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy", max_depth = 4)
Tree_Loan
```

and it displays

```
DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=4)
```

However, it should display something in the form of (this is from a different lab I've done using Skills Network Labs):

```
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='entropy', max_depth=4,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='best')
```

The best I can tell is that it is not importing the decision tree classifier.  I have the same problem with svm from sklearn.  Other functions in scikit-learn like train test split and k nearest neighbors work fine.  A classmate says the rest of my code is correct and there is no reason for the error.  What might be causing it?

Comment: SORRY!  I acidentally deleted your comment Mustafa Aydin.  
He said that the output I"m seeing is actually repr(Tree_Loan) and it displays the parameters that were given to estimator with non-default values only.  

If that's the case, how do I get it to display the default values as well?  I should note that I use the same syntax and options in a project in Skills Network Labs and it displays them all, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the deleted comment, there's no issue. If you have a look here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html then you see that most of the values you saw in online version are simply default values.

Comment: @J.Alexander No worries, I thought I'd write an answer as to why & how to get the full output and deleted the comment `:)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64516612/10495893

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* importing the `DecisionTreeClassifier`, no problem there. But by default, `sklearn` prints only *the parameters that were given to estimator with non-default values*, from [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f6e6ad2d9e9172c55c778392b27b69c6af87bd98/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py#L87) function.

But if you want to see the "full" output, you can set the configuration of `print_changed_only` to `False` via `sklearn._config.set_config` like so:

```
>>> from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
>>> tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy", max_depth=4)

>>> # only displays the changed parameters
>>> tree
DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=4)

>>> from sklearn._config import get_config, set_config

>>> # default setting
>>> get_config()["print_changed_only"]
True

>>> # now changing it 
>>> set_config(print_changed_only=False)

# now we get the default values, too
>>> tree

DecisionTreeClassifier(ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None, criterion='entropy',
                       max_depth=4, max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
                       min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                       min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                       min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort='deprecated',
                       random_state=None, splitter='best')
```